# Any way to make hasOwnProperty typecheck?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Given some interface

```
interface Foo {
  foo?: string
}
```

is there any way to make the hasOwnProperty check the property against the interface?

```
const f: Foo = { foo: 'a' }
f.hasOwnProperty('foo') // works fine
f.hasOwnProperty('fo')  // want this to throw error "fo" doesn't exist in Foo
```

I've considered doing instead

```
f.foo !== undefined
```

but that isn't exactly equivalent since hypothetically `foo` could exist but be assigned to undefined i.e.

```
const f: Foo = { foo: undefined }
f.hasOwnProperty('foo') // true
f.foo !== undefined     // false
```

I know I could write my own function that wraps hasOwnProperty with the correct type signature like `has<T extends object>(obj: T, key: keyof T): boolean`, but wondering if there's a more native alternative.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your solution. If you make an interface you should have clearly defined shared properties. What's the point of sharing them in an interface if you dont even know what type it will be?

Answer (score -1):

obj.hasOwnProperty() checks if it has that property, not the value of the property, hence no need to typecheck.

I think you need to rethink your solution. If you make an interface you should have clearly defined shared properties. What's the point of sharing them in an interface if you dont even know what type it will be?

Comment: Hmm I get that, but what I'm saying is that if you've defined an interface for an object, there's no point accepting arguments that you know are not a part of that interface. Most likely what's happening is that you made a typo rather than that you're looking for some random property that can never exist on your object. Hence the need for type checking.

Comment: But .hasOwnProperty() does not check the inherited "chain" only it's own object.

Comment: exactly...so why would I check `f` in the above example for anything except `foo`.

Comment: You can use 'in' .. like "t" in obj, it will look in the prototype chain

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing two different things here.

TypeScript's type system only exists at compile time, while `hasOwnProperty()` is a runtime call.

You typically will not get type information at runtime because it is just JavaScript.

Also, you should not do such test anyway, because JavaScript (and hence TypeScript) is dynamically typed, which enables duck typing.

Consider this:

```
function doSomething(x: Foo) {
  // ...
}
let y = { foo: 'foo', fo: 'fo' }
doSomething(y)
```

Should `doSomething()` throws an error in this case?

At consumption (`doSomething()`), you would only concern about what you need, and not forcing the caller to pass in ONLY what you need.

On the other hand, TypeScript compiler does aware that typo is a common issue and will throw compile error with the following code:

```
// Argument of type '{ fo: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo'.
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fo' does not exist in type 'Foo'.
doSomething({ fo: 'foo' })
```

This check only occurs if you passing in object literal directly. This code doesn't trigger error:

```
let y = { fo: 'foo' }
doSomething(y)
```